# Setting different reporting services url via IReportServerConnection

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a asp.net app that needs to display report. I have problem using more than one reporting services urls via IReportServerConnection.

Specifically, I need to display report from different report services url on different page via IReportServerConnection. Each page uses report viewer web forms control. The problem is that how to assign different report services url for different page.

Below is the settings related to IReportServerConnection:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="ReportServer.ReportServerConnection" />
  </appSettings>

    public class ReportServerConnection : IReportServerConnection {

    public Uri ReportServerUrl { get; set;}

      ...

    }
```

Below shows report viewer control that is used on different page that needs different reporting services urls:

```
  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server"             
        ProcessingMode="Remote">
            <ServerReport  />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Thanks in advance.